# show/hide elements with If statement depending on var value

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I have a simple logic issue whereby I am try to show/hide elements depending on a variable who's value is taken from a query string. The getting of the value works as I have managed to echo the var to the console. The trouble i'm having seems to be with my if statements below. Can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong please?

JQUERY...

```
if ($tree_option = 'smell') {
    console.log(tree_option);

      $('.option').addClass('off');
      $('.option-2').removeClass('off');
}

else if ($tree_option = 'bushiness') {
    console.log(tree_option);

      $('.option').addClass('off');
      $('.option-1').removeClass('off');
}

else if ($tree_option = 'needle-retention') {
    console.log(tree_option);

      $('.option').addClass('off');
      $('.option-3').removeClass('off');
}
```

html...

```
                    <button class="small-12 large-4 button option option-3 text-center" data-question="needle-retention"><div class="circle-container"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/tree3.png"></div><div class="">Needle Retention</div></button>
                    <button class="small-12 large-4 button option option-1 text-center" data-question="bushiness"><div class="circle-container"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/tree1.png"></div><div class="">Bushiness</div></button>
                    <button class="small-12 large-4 button option option-2 text-center" data-question="smell"><div class="circle-container"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/tree2.png"></div><div class="">Smell</div></button>
```

Comment: you're assigning the value rather than comparing it $tree_option = 'bushiness' means tree_option IS business, you mean $tree_option ==='bushiness'

Comment: `$tree_option = 'smell'` should be `$tree_option == 'smell'`

Answer (score 3):

`=` is an assignment, so you're setting the variable instead of checking its value. What you want is to check if the variable is set to the given string/value. In order to do that, use the `==` or `===` operators.

Comment: Thanks, i just tried `==` but i get a console error saying `Uncaught ReferenceError: $tree_option is not defined`. However the variable is defined and the value is echoed in the log. I also tried `===` but no luck.

Comment: Show us your full code then, where the variabla is defined. If you get that error code, it obviously isn't defined in the variable scobe where you're checking its value.

Comment: Ha! I just removed the `$' from `$tree_option` and it worked :)